# Run source in bash execution

Tags: bash

Quick run down of what I'm doing, I'm making python development environments on my computer using [virtualenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/blob/master/docs/dev/virtualenvs.rst). I'm not one to remember all these commands, so I like to build simple(noob-ish) script that will help me.

#### Problem

As you see on [step 2](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/blob/master/docs/dev/virtualenvs.rst#basic-usage) in the `Basic Usage` section of the documentation. I need to run a command:

`$ source venv/bin/activate`

This activates my python environment. So I've tried a mixture of `functions` and `eval`. As mentioned, I am a bit of a noob when it comes to bash scripts.

## My Code

File: `fpyenv`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# $ cd ~/scripts/
# $ chmod u+x <filename>.sh

activateSrc(){

    eval '$(source "${1}"/bin/activate)'

}
if [[ $1 == '' ]];
    then
    printf "ERROR: Missing Filename\n"
else
    printf "Creating Virtual Environment $1\n"
    # This creates the environment
    virtualenv $1  
    printf "Do you want to activate $1 as your virtual environment?(y/n)\n"
    # Get answer from user
    read answer 
    if [[ $answer != 'y' ]];
        # Said No 
        then 
        printf "Did not set $1 as your virtual environment\n"
    else
        # Said Yes
        activateSrc $1
        printf "Set $1 as your virtual environment\n"
    fi
fi
```

## This is what it should look like:

### Step 1

```
myComputer $ fpyenv venv
```

#### returns

```
Creating Virtual Environment venv
Do you want to activate venv as your virtual environment?(y/n)
```

### Step 2(user inputs y/n)

```
y
```

#### returns

```
Set venv as your virtual environment
(venv)myComputer $
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
Set venv as your virtual environment
myComputer $
```

So it doesn't run the `source venv/bin/activate`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've looked through many answers, but given that `source` is commonly used in a different way in bash scripts, the answers I'm getting are no help. Thank you in advance!

## FIX:

Change `activateSrc` to:

```bsh
activateSrc(){

    source $1/bin/activate

}
```

And execute script like this:

```
myComputer $ . fpyenv venv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs `source` just as written. The thing is that you need to source *this new script as well*, otherwise it just runs in a subshell and any changes made by the sourced script are lost when the subshell exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So are you saying create a new bash script file that simply runs this command? Or how do I work around this?

Comment: Got it thanks! Your answer confused me a bit because I didn't really understand the bash script lingo. I hope you don't mind, but I'm going to edit your answer to reflect what exactly I did to execute it correctly. Thank you again!